# In MySql, using Python, how to INSERT INTO tables and columns, depending on variables?

Tags: python, mysql

I am building an interface in Python to get access to different queries in some big data tables (queries such as insert, search, predefined ones, etc.). The problem is that there are a few different tables which contain each a number of columns... So I would want to modularize my code and MySql queries, so that depending on which table we want to insert data to and to which columns these data concern, it will know what MySql command it will have to execute.

I saw that we can use variables for values, for example :

```
sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
values = ("val1", "val2")
mycursor.execute(sql, values)
```

Is it possible to have something similar with `table_name`and `columns` ? To have something for example like :

```
sql = "INSERT INTO (%s) (%s, %s) VALUES (%s, %s)"
table = "table_name"
columns = ("col1", "col2")
values = ("val1", "val2")
mycursor.execute(sql, table, columns, values)
```

With that, it would be far easier for me to initialize `table`, `columns`and `values` when needed (for example when the user clicks a button, enters values in some text fields, etc.) than having a lot of such `sql` queries, one for each table and each possible subset of columns.

I am not sure that it is all clear with my pretty random english, if you need some more information feel free to ask !

Thank you in advance for your time,

Sanimys

Answer (score 0):

For the few of you that will see this while looking for an answer, in fact this is pretty easy ! You can do pretty much exaclty like I proposed, for example :

```
sql = "INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES %s"
table = "table_name"
columns = "(col1, col2)"
values = "(val1, val2)"
mycursor.execute(sql % (table, columns, values))
```

Where every element is a `string`.

By doing that, you can have some nice dynamic computations, such as :

```
sql = "INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES %s"
table = "table_name"
values = "(val1, val2)"

// Some code

def compute_columns(list_of_columns_to_insert):
    col = "("
    for c in list_of_columns_to_insert:
        col = col + "'" + c + "', " 

    col = col[:-2] + ")"
    return col

// Some code generating a list of columns that we want to insert to

columns = compute_columns(list_of_columns_to_insert)
mycursor.execute(sql % (columns, values))
```

Here you go, hope that it could help someone that struggles like me !